# some question about matrix multiplicaiton?

Tags: python, numpy

I want to perform the following operations:

Given a n by m matrix M and a k by 1 vector V, We first take the product of v and rows of M.

Here the product of v with a row of M gives a k by m matrix. So we expect n k by m matrices after the multiplications. Next, we need to take the sum of the n matrices and then divide by n. Like take the average.

Concretely, `let v=[1,2,3] ,M=[[1,2][3,4][5,6]]`

`return average(v,M)` gives `([[1,2],[2,4],[3,6]]+[[3,4],[6,8],[9,12]]+[[5,6],[10,12],[15,18]])/3`

So
I would do something like

```
temp= np.zeros(len(v),np.shape(M)[1])
for i in range(np.shape(M)[0]):
    temp=temp+v[:,None]*M[i,:][None,:]
return temp/np.shape(M)[0]
```

I'm wondering if there is a building method like that in numpy?

Answer (score 0):

I think using the outer method of the multiply ufunc does what you want.

```
M=np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
v=np.array([1,2,3])

res = np.multiply.outer(M, v)
res 
# array([[[ 1,  2,  3],
#         [ 2,  4,  6]],
#        [[ 3,  6,  9],
#         [ 4,  8, 12]],
#        [[ 5, 10, 15],
#         [ 6, 12, 18]]])

res/M.shape[0] 
# array([[[0.33333333, 0.66666667, 1.        ],
#         [0.66666667, 1.33333333, 2.        ]],
#        [[1.        , 2.        , 3.        ],
#         [1.33333333, 2.66666667, 4.        ]],
#        [[1.66666667, 3.33333333, 5.        ],
#         [2.        , 4.        , 6.        ]]])

res.shape     # (3, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [201]: v = np.array([1,2,3])                                                 
In [202]: v.shape                                                               
Out[202]: (3,)              # NOT (3,1)
In [203]: M = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])                                     
In [204]: M.shape                                                               
Out[204]: (3, 2)
```

Your calculation:

```
In [206]: temp= np.zeros([len(v),np.shape(M)[1]]) 
     ...: for i in range(np.shape(M)[0]): 
     ...:     temp=temp+v[:,None]*M[i,:][None,:] 
     ...: temp1 = temp/np.shape(M)[0]                                           
In [207]: temp                                                                  
Out[207]: 
array([[ 9., 12.],
       [18., 24.],
       [27., 36.]])
In [208]: temp1                                                                 
Out[208]: 
array([[ 3.,  4.],
       [ 6.,  8.],
       [ 9., 12.]])
```

Doing the broadcasted multiplication on all `i` at once:

```
In [211]: v[:,None]*M[:,None,:]       # or v[None,:,None]                                          
Out[211]: 
array([[[ 1,  2],
        [ 2,  4],
        [ 3,  6]],

       [[ 3,  4],
        [ 6,  8],
        [ 9, 12]],

       [[ 5,  6],
        [10, 12],
        [15, 18]]])
In [212]: _.sum(axis=0)     # and the sum                                                    
Out[212]: 
array([[ 9, 12],
       [18, 24],
       [27, 36]])
```

With einsum:

```
In [214]: np.einsum('j,ik->ijk', v, M)                                          
Out[214]:   # same a 211
...
```

doing the sum on `i`:

```
In [215]: np.einsum('j,ik->jk', v, M)                                           
Out[215]: 
array([[ 9, 12],
       [18, 24],
       [27, 36]])
```

This makes it obvious that we could sum on the first dimension of `M` first:

```
In [217]: v[:,None]*M.sum(axis=0)[None,:]                                       
Out[217]: 
array([[ 9, 12],
       [18, 24],
       [27, 36]])
```

and even take the mean on that dimension:

```
In [218]: v[:,None]*M.mean(axis=0)[None,:]                                      
Out[218]: 
array([[ 3.,  4.],
       [ 6.,  8.],
       [ 9., 12.]])
```

To use `dot`, matrix multiplication, we have to construct a (3,3) `v` array to work with the (3,2) `M`:

```
In [222]: np.column_stack([v,v,v])@M                                            
Out[222]: 
array([[ 9, 12],
       [18, 24],
       [27, 36]])
```

`np.broadcast_to(v[:,None],(3,3))@M` is more memory efficient.

Or using `@` as an `outer` with a dummy size 1 dimension:

```
In [227]: v[:,None]@M.mean(axis=0, keepdims=True)                               
Out[227]: 
array([[ 3.,  4.],
       [ 6.,  8.],
       [ 9., 12.]])
```